# clock-wise 90-degree rotation of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rotation

I am trying to construct a function `f` that can rotate a matrix in a clock-wise manner.

The function should looks like this

```
f <- function(mat, k) {...}
```

where `mat` is the matrix, `k` is the times we perform 90-degree clock-wise rotation. Let's say, `k=1` means we rotate the matrix 90 degrees, `k=2` means 180 degrees, and so on.

If `k > 1`, I want to save all those rotated matrices (for i = 1,2,....,k) into a list, such that I can track how the rotation evolves.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use `rot90` from package `pracma` to implement the fundamental rotation functionality.

The code below use a recursion method to save all those rotated matrices through `0` to `k` times of clock-wise rotations

```
library(pracma)

f <- function(mat, k) {
  if (k==0) return(list(mat))
  u <- f(mat,(k-1)%%4)
  c(u,list(rot90(tail(u,1)[[1]])))
}
```

---

**Example**

Given a matrix `mat` like below

```
mat <- matrix(1:12,nrow = 4)
```

we will see

```
> f(mat,4)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    9   10   11   12
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    1    2    3    4

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   12    8    4
[2,]   11    7    3
[3,]   10    6    2
[4,]    9    5    1

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    3    2    1
[2,]    8    7    6    5
[3,]   12   11   10    9

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
```

---

Since the first element of list is the original matrix `mat`, you can remove it via

```
f(mat,k)[-1]
```